# How to Group lists within a list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a list of 7 vectors, I would like to group the lists into 4 lists of vectors each.

```
B2 <- list ( c (12 , 47 ,137 ,170), c(44 , 47 ,135, 170) , c(12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 59 , 61 , 67 , 76 , 80 , 84 ,135, 148, 170) , c(44 , 47 , 84 ,135 ,170) , c(12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 59 , 61 , 67 , 76 , 80 , 84 ,135, 148, 156, 159, 164, 170) , c(12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 84 ,135 ,170) , c(12 , 28 , 44 , 47 , 84, 135, 170)) 

# I would like to create four groups (lists) as per the following index of consecutive list sequence)    

Subgroup <- c(2,4,5,7)

# Desired Output

  B2 <- list ( list ( c (12 , 47 ,137 ,170), c(44 , 47 ,135, 170)) , list ( c(12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 59 , 61 , 67 , 76 , 80 , 84 ,135, 148, 170) , c(44 , 47 , 84 ,135 ,170)) , list ( c(12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 59 , 61 , 67 , 76 , 80 , 84 ,135, 148, 156, 159, 164, 170)) , list ( c (12 , 28 , 34 , 44 , 47 , 84 ,135 ,170) , c(12 , 28 , 44 , 47 , 84, 135, 170)))
```

Comment: I think a reason why there are no upvotes on answers here is because it's hard to determine exactly what it is you are doing to go from the given list to the resulting list.  Could you provide a bit more explanation on how `Subgroup` is used to determine your resulting `B2`?

Comment: @ Richard Scriven, This is just an example as per the rationale of segments as to achive a Desired Output which is also an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split` and `rep`:

```
split(B2, rep(1:length(Subgroup), diff(c(0, Subgroup))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `sequence`

```
i1 <- sequence(Subgroup)
i2 <- !duplicated(i1)
res <- split(B2[i1[i2]],cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(i1)<0))[i2])
all.equal(res, Out, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or as @Chris mentioned in the comments,

```
lst <- Map(`:`,  c(1,head(Subgroup,-1)+1), Subgroup)
lapply(lst, function(i) B2[i])
```

Comment: Slightly simpler would be ``Map(`:`, c(1,Subgroup[1:(length(Subgroup)-1)] + 1), Subgroup)`` instead, followed by your original `lapply(lst, function(i) B2[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
rng = data.frame(1+c(0, head(Subgroup,-1)), Subgroup)
apply(rng, 1,function(x) B2[x[1]:x[2]])
```